# Wordpress Site not logging-in

Tags: php, wordpress, installation

So I'm completely new to working with WordPress and I've had to figure this out by watching YouTube videos and reading articles. I'm not a programmer, all I really understand is HTML & CSS.

So I finished the site on the localhost and I tried to upload it to my hosting service. I created a database and my hosting provider walked me through on creating a subdomain. After that was completed I logged into the admin side of to redirect the URLs. Once I clicked 'save' it logged me out and when I tried to log back in it gave me this error "ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress." However, the cookies are enabled and the site is live in its subdomain. When I go to test.mydomain.com it works, there's a few things broken but it's showing up. For example, when I click a link it takes me to a localhost url but if i click on the link again it takes me back to the test.mydomain.com url. Plus, when i go to the admin site it's still giving me the error. I have no idea how to go about fixing this. I tried to figure it out but I don't really understand since I'm not familiar with WordPress. Please help!

Comment: I imagine there’s still some references to `localhost` in `wp_config.php` or in your database. You’ll want to make sure they’re all appropriately changed.

Comment: thank you so much for replying! I did see notice this: /** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');   what should I change localhost to?

Comment: Well, WordPress isn’t complaining about the database, so `DB_HOST` is probably okay. But if there’s other references, those could be a problem.

Comment: No I think that's the only reference. Thanks though! I've just never done this and I already screwed something up and I'm afraid to do anything else because I don't want to screw something else up too.

Comment: @Rixy Error is occuring due to have extra spaces in your `functions.php` or the files include in `functions.php` you may look through the `view-source` if you getting spaces just before  `<!DOCTYPE html>` it means you have to remove extra spaces. or if you dont know how to remove then contact any developer.